# What does if(';') do and mean?

Tags: if-statement

What does any char,int etc. in if parenthesis do and how does it work?
For example: If I write if(';'){...} what does program do? Does the program or compiler do for that if statement? Do they search ';' in input. Thanks for your helps. I mean: "Does the program search for ';' character in input?-Assume that it takes input from user" . Language was C++.Also I got the answer.PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: which language are you asking this?  PHP, java, C...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is in the parentheses will be interpreted as a boolean value, either true or false.  If it's a character, then in most programming languages, this interpretation happens via two steps:

1. the character is interpreted as an integer, usually its ASCII value
2. the integer is interpreted as a boolean (usually false for 0 and true for any other number)

So `if(';') {...}` will have the same effect as `if(true) {...}`

In some programming languages, strings interpreted as a boolean value are true if they have at least one character and false if they are empty (have length zero).  So again, this would cause the code to run.